# if i select dropdown option 1 then i get another dropdown only one record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 dropdown ,
1st is static 'displayAnswer' and 2nd is 'correctAnswer'
here i select 'displayAnswer' option 2 then i get only 1 and 2 in 'correctAnswer' my 2nd dropdown,
or i select 3 then i get only 1, 2 and 3 in 'correctAnswer' my 2nd dropdown,
or i select 4 then i get 1, 2, 3 and 4 in 'correctAnswer' my 2nd dropdown.
using Mvc Razor.
Plz Help Me.

thnks.

Comment: you can get the selected value from dropdown(display answer) and through viewbag you can bind that selected value to the other dropdown(selectcorrectanswer)

Comment: You can use viewbag or Session to pass values to next dropdown

Comment: plz show us the code :) What have you tried so far? And what is the intended behaviour?

Comment: Don't use viewbag. This can be achieved using `jQuery`. Always show what you have done, don't just expect an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `jQuery` irrespective if you are using `ASP.NET MVC`. It is one way of achieving what you need and there might be other solutions that you can follow, but this worked for me.

Below are samples from my code, you can modify it to fit in with your scenario. In my sample I am going to be working with departments and units when adding a new user. A department consists out of different units. So when a department is selected from the first drop down then all that department's units will be displayed in the second drop down.

Let me start with the view (page). It accepts a view model called `CreateUserViewModel`. A view model should always be used instead of passing through your domain model.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Users.CreateUserViewModel
```

The HTML markup representing my two drop downs:

```
<tr>
     <td class="edit-label">Department <span class="required">*</span></td>
     <td>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(
               x => x.DepartmentId,
               new SelectList(Model.Departments, "Id", "Name", Model.DepartmentId),
               "-- Select --",
               new { id = "Departments" }
          )
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DepartmentId)
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class="edit-label">Unit <span class="required">*</span></td>
     <td>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(
               x => x.UnitId,
               new SelectList(Model.Units, "Id", "Name", Model.UnitId),
               "-- Select --",
               new { id = "Units" }
          )
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UnitId)
     </td>
</tr>
```

My `CreateUserViewModel` class (partial):

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
     public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

     public int UnitId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
```

My `Department` class:

```
public class Department
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My `Unit` class:

```
public class Unit
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

When the view is loaded for the first time I populate the departments drop down and I have the units drop down empty.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     CreateUserViewModel viewModel = new CreateUserViewModel
     {
          Departments = departmentService.GetAll(),
          Units = Enumerable.Empty<Unit>()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Getting back to my view (page) I used `jQuery` to populate my second drop down:

```
<script>

     function resetDropDown(targetDropDown) {
          var items = '';
          items = '<option>-- Select --</option>';
          $(targetDropDown).empty();
          $(targetDropDown).html(items);
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Departments").change(function () {
               var url = '@Url.Action("GetUnitsByDepartmentId", "User")';
               var departmentId = $("#Departments").val();

               if (departmentId == '') {
                    resetDropDown($('#Units'));
                    return;
               }

               $.getJSON(url, { departmentId: departmentId }, function (data) {
                    $('#Units').empty();
                    var items = '<option>-- Select --</option>';

                    $.each(data, function (i, unit) {
                         items += "<option value='" + unit.Id + "'>" + unit.Name + "</option>";
                    });

                    $('#Units').html(items);
               });
          });
     });

</script>
```

In my controller there is an action method that returns my units as a `JSON` result:

```
public ActionResult GetUnitsByDepartmentId(int departmentId)
{
     IEnumerable<Unit> units = unitService.GetUnitsByDepartmentId(departmentId);

     var displayedUnits = units.Select(x => new
     {
          Id = x.Id.ToString(),
          Name = x.Name
     });

     return Json(displayedUnits, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This solution might not be perfect but it will guide you in the right direction. All the best.